# How to compare two lists of custom objects for some properties using streams in Java?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

What is the best way to compares the items of two lists by (only) some of their properties?

```
public class A {
    private String type;
    private String value;
    private String foo;
    private String bar;
}

List<A> listA = List.of(...);
List<A> listB = List.of(...);
```

I tried

```
return listA.stream().anyMatch( a -> listB.stream().anyMatch(b -> {
    a.getType().equals(b.getType());
    a.getValue().equals(b.getValue());}
));
```

...but this doesn't work.

It would be sufficient to find any/the first match and return true then or false if no match can be found.

### Update / Example

---

```
A a1 = new A();
a1.setType("AB");
a1.setValue("xx");

A a2 = new A();
a2.setType("XY");
a2.setValue("00");

List<A> listA = List.of(a1, a2);

A b1 = new A();
b1.setType("AB");
b1.setValue("xx");

A b2 = new A();
b2.setType("XY");
b2.setValue("");

List<A> listB = List.of(b1, b2);
```

Using these lists in (with `compVal = listA` and `expVal = listB`):

```
public static boolean isValid(final List<A> compAs, final List<A> expAs) {
    
    return compAs.stream().anyMatch(a -> expAs.stream().anyMatch(e -> {
    return c.getType().equals(e.getType()) &&
                c.getValue().equals(e.getValue())
    }
}
```

an `assertFalse(isValid())` test fails (returns *true* while *false* is expected).

I tried with

```
return e.equals(c)
```

as well.

Using allMatch() ends up in a failure if the list are really equal.

Comment: what exactly do you want as result? a List containing the matches? "this doesn't work", can you be more clear on that part? does it give an error? does it return different results compared to what you want?

Comment: @Stultuske `It would be sufficient to find any/the first match and return true then or false if no match can be found.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both properties to match, it should be:

```
return listA.stream()
            .anyMatch( a -> listB.stream()
                                 .anyMatch(b -> a.getType().equals(b.getType()) &&
                                                a.getValue().equals(b.getValue())));
```

This will compare all pairs of elements of the two lists until a match is found.

EDIT:

If you require that each element of the first `List` have a matching element of the second `List`, use `allMatch` in the outer `Stream`:

```
return listA.stream()
            .allMatch( a -> listB.stream()
                                 .anyMatch(b -> a.getType().equals(b.getType()) &&
                                                a.getValue().equals(b.getValue())));
```

Comment: It was just the '&&'? LOL

Comment: @du-it not just the `&&`. The body block of your lambda expression had no return statement.

Comment: Look at what I tried: return listA.stream()... So...I had a return statement.

Comment: @du-it I was referring to this block: `{
    a.getType().equals(b.getType());
    a.getValue().equals(b.getValue());}` which had no return statement.

Comment: Well, okay, ...but in your suggestion there is no return statement as well!?! (I added it by myself because IntelliJ complained. ;-) )

Comment: @du-it lambda expression body can be either an expression or a block. An expression (as in my answer) doesn't require a return statement. A block (`{...}`), as in your question, requires a return statement (assuming the lambda expression's method has a non-void return type).

Comment: Thank you!!! Now I see the difference. :-)

Comment: I tested around and it seems as if the solution is not quite correct. I updated my question.

Comment: @du-it why do you expect `false` to be returned in the example you added? Earlier you wrote that true should be returned if any match is found.

Comment: I have to apologize!!! I need to compare EACH item. Like two nested for loops.

Comment: @du-it in that case, I believe you should change the first (outer) `anyMatch` to `allMatch`.